# Slow Script Error in IE When running sahi test

Tags: testing, internet-explorer-8, automated-tests, functional-testing, sahi

IE8 is throwing a slow script error when we try and run the following sahi command (in tests/playback or "evaluate expression"):

```
_popup("Editor")._click(_image("Menu, _near(_span("Activity"))));
```

It works in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sahi.co.in/forums/viewtopic.php?id=1970 has the developer's solution if anyone else runs into this. MS Support Article ID: 175500 also describes a registry hack to push back the errors all together.